# Does anyone know about ATcommands for satellitephone(isatphone 2.1). AT + ISAT_OBEX = 1 What is purpose of it. can you suggest other AT commands also

Tags: at-command, hyperterminal

Does anyone know how to use AT commands for satellite phone(isatphone 2.1). `AT + ISAT_OBEX = 1`

When I run that command using hyperteminal, it's giving me: 
`+CME: 25`.

What is the purpose of it? Can you suggest other AT commands also?

I tried in hyperterminal as follows:

```
AT
OK
AT+ISAT_OBEX=1
+CME ERRO: 25 (refer img1)
Some of AT commds are working like
AT+CGSN
AT+GCAP,
```

When I tried to read contacts using `AT+CPBR`, it's not giving me the desired result.

Refer to the following screen shots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]